# .replace only replacing first value

Tags: pandas, replace

I have the following code:

```
df_demo['Age'] = df_demo['Age'].replace([23842674135270370, 
23842674044440370, 23842674044420370, 23842674044430370], 
['18-24', '25-34', '35-44', '45+'])
```

(The numbers are ad id tags, and I'm trying to replace them to the age groups they are targeting.)

The code is only reading the first number and replacing it (to 18-24). The rest of the numbers are not reading and replacing. If I flip the order of the numbers (like move the 25-34 pairing to the first set) it replaces that first pairing but none of the others.

I have exactly the same construction for .replace() -- using two lists within the () -- further up in my program and it's working perfectly. But this one is not, and I can't figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Are values integers? If strings add `'` like `23842674135270370` to `'23842674135270370'`

Comment: It work on my side

Comment: @jezrael they are integers -- first time around mistake was that I had '' around them and it wasn't able to convert string / integer.

Comment: And still problem?

Comment: Do you convert by `df_demo['Age'].str.strip().astype(int).replace...` ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes... it's still only reading the first in the set of replacements.

Comment: @jezrael Yup still only first set!! Have converted the entire column so it is uniform, still not working.

Comment: Idea - replace by dict like `d = {23842674135270370:'18-24', 23842674044440370:'25-34',23842674044420370:'35-44',23842674044430370:'45+'}` - replace(d)

Comment: @jezrael Exact same issue -- only replacing first one.

What's really confusing me is that if you flip the order of replacement (putting 25-34 numbers before 18-24, for example) it still only works for the first one (replacing the 25-34 set instead of the 18-24). So it's not an issue with the data, it's all input correctly.

Thank you for your help... not entirely sure where to go!

Comment: there is problem with data I think. Is possible send me your data to my email if not confidental? Email is in my profile.

Comment: try restarting your python instance (ipython, jupyter, or whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working convert column `Age` to `string` by `dtype` and then replace `string`s by another one:

```
df_demo = pd.read_csv('demographics - Sheet1.csv', dtype={'Age':str})
print (df_demo.tail())

190  191  23842674135270370        Yes
191  192  23842674135270370        Yes
192  193  23842674044420370        Yes
193  194  23842674135270370        Yes
194  195  23842674044420370        Yes

df_demo['Age'] = df_demo['Age'].replace(
['23842674135270370','23842674044440370','23842674044420370','23842674044430370'], 
['18-24', '25-34', '35-44', '45+'])

print (df_demo.tail())
    Name    Age Newsletter
190  191  18-24        Yes
191  192  18-24        Yes
192  193  35-44        Yes
193  194  18-24        Yes
194  195  35-44        Yes
```